# Table max height as parent div - with scrollbar

Tags: html, css

[image]

As you can see by the image, I'm building an HTML page using mostly `flexboxes`.
However I'm finding it hard do make the HTML "table" display a scrollbar on excessive height.

- the fuchsia-dotted element is the "table"
- the turquoise-dotted element is the "paginator"

Those two elements are contained inside a `div`.
The `div` itself is contained inside a `flexbox`

```
div#job-table {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   border: 2px solid black;

   table {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 2px dotted fuchsia;
   }

   mat-paginator {
      margin: 5px;
      border: 2px dotted turquoise;
   }
}
```

What I'd like to obtain is the "table" to display a vertical scrollbar on content overflow, while the "paginator" should stay always fixed at the bottom of its container `div`, `job-table`.

The HTML is as follow (I omitted some details as it is build with Angular Material)

```
<div id="job-table">
    <!-- Main table -->
    <table
        mat-table
        multiTemplateDataRows
    > ...
    </table>

    <!-- Pagination -->
    <mat-paginator
      ...
    ></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

EDIT: I tried containing the table in a `div`, with the same result

```
div#job-table {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   border: 2px solid black;

   #test-wrapper {
      flex: 1;
      overflow: auto;
      border: 2px solid greenyellow;

      table {
         width: 100%;
         border: 2px dotted fuchsia;
      }
   }

   mat-paginator {
      border: 2px dotted turquoise;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put table in a container and give some height to it and add `overflowY:scroll`. thanks.

Comment: The container height must be dynamic, however, is it ok?

Comment: if you don't give height to the container then the size of the table and the container will keep increasing as entries comes in it. thanks

Comment: But the available height should increase as the browser page gets resized

Comment: okay please add a code snippet.. so we can understand it better. thanks

Comment: You can see it by the image. In that image the table should display a scrollbar, *not* overflowing the parent. If I resize the browser page to make it higher, than the scrollbar should disappear

Comment: use overflow:auto.. scrollbar will only show when the table is going out of the container.

Comment: I tried it, with the same result. See updated question

Comment: you need give height to #test-wrapper.. or-else it will not work. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The table element has no overflow property as from the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table), so you'll have to contain it inside a div, which can have `overflowY: auto` (to only show the scroll when necessary.

The div need to be configured correctly to adapt to the contained table. I usually take help from [this playground](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/) when experimenting with flexbox.